# What is this symbol (appears before line break)?

Tags: css, cms, text, content-encoding

On Pixel 6 (Android) using the Chrome browser, there's this strange symbol I've never seen before that usually appears before some of the line breaks on my website. Does anyone have any idea what this symbol is (see screenshot)[image: strange symbol]

For context, I've copy/pasted text into a CMS (Webflow).

Comment: Have you tried opening your site up in Chrome on desktop, using [Device Mode](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/)? You could right-click inspect element, and the DOM might give you some clues.

Comment: The thing is I'm unable to see the issue on the desktop. The issue just seems to be happening on the Chrome mobile browser on the Pixel 6 only.

Answer (score 1):

Because this visual artifact shows up on your physical device but not in Chrome for Desktop's [Device Mode](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/) emulation, I wonder if this may be some kind of CSS or other rendering issue rather than a character symbol in the DOM. In my experience, device mode is faithful to how the site should actually look on a physical device.

I would try clearing site data on both the physical device and Chrome for Desktop to rule out any difference in state. Then if the issue still occurs on the physical Pixel but not on the emulated device, you could try attaching the Chrome debugger to your phone using Chrome's [Remote debug Android devices](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/) feature. Using the debugger, you could use the Elements view to scan the DOM for anything that could be causing this on the physical device, then compare to the Elements view on the emulated device.